# LinearLayout Not Showing

Tags: android, android-layout, remoteview

I believe my problem stems from my use of weights and the RelativeLayout that immediately follows the LinearLayout not containing any...I can't get it to work though.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish (focusing on the center area with the background image) I get this by making background of LinearLayout the image...I can't do this with RemoteViews):
[image]

Here is what I get with the xml that follows:
[image]

```
<LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/forecast_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="4.5"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/widget_bg_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/widget_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/current_ll"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/update_time_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/at"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/current_temp_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:text="35 F"
                    android:textSize="44dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/current_short_text_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                    android:text="partly cloudy"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_divider"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/extended_forecast_ll"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/day_one_ll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/day_one_image"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/widget_icon"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/day_one_daytv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="WED"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/day_one_hilo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="155 / 125"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    />
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/day_two_ll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/day_two_image"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/widget_icon"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/day_two_daytv"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="WED"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/day_two_hilo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="55 / 25"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my adjusted xml layout...removed weightsum and related items from outer most LinearLayout:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/forecast_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        >
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/widget_bg_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/al_widgetbg_01_05"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/current_ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/update_time_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/at"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_temp_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:text="35 F"
                android:textSize="44dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_short_text_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
                android:text="partly cloudy"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_divider"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/extended_forecast_ll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_divider"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/day_one_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/day_one_image"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/widget_icon"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/day_one_daytv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="WED"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/day_one_hilo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="155 / 125"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/white"
                />
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/day_two_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/day_two_image"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/day_two_daytv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="WED"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/day_two_hilo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="55 / 25"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not positioning any of your items inside the RelativeLayout, so none of the items have any idea where to be placed. Unlike LinearLayout, you need to tell each item where you want it positioned relative to the other views inside it and the parent itself.

You need to use positioning parameters to accomplish this, like:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/aView"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_below="@id/aView"
```

etc...

You should read up on the other RelativeLayout alignment rules: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: This is not the case for my layout.  I did fix it and what I needed to do was to remove the weightsum=2 from the outer LL as well as the weights that coincided at the current_ll and the forecast_ll.  I want the LinearLayout to be on top of the Relative and then the Linears within are positioned through orientation and weights.